# How to prove the following ring is not locally compact.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-number-theory

I read the process of the construct of Adele $A_F$,
it take a fitting subring of $\prod_v^{}{F_v}$,which $v$ represent the valuation of number field $F$.

We not study $\prod_v^{}{F_v}$ directly ,because it's so big, and not locally compact ,I don't know how to prove it's not locally compact,can you give me some hit?

Thankyou for sharing your idea!

Comment: A product of infinitely many non-compact spaces is never locally compact (see Engelking, General Topology 3.3.13 )